# Javascript function that runs a part of its code only once without the use of external code

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Trying to make a function that runs on its own using private variables. Version 1 turned out pretty good, but for it to work I have to input 2 parameters and use

Other things that I've tried are in version 2 and 3 where the variables aren't global, but it'd great if they all were inside the function.

```
    // Independent functions

    // description: Attempt to create a function that runs a part of its code
    // only once, and later ignores it. The function needs to run without the use of external code (like global variables).
```

[Update] It finally worked. Huge thanks to ocBiermann, for mentioning that functions in javascript are also objects. Here's how you do it with arrays.

```
    function Ind(x) {
      if (Ind.random === undefined) {
        sum = [];
        Ind.random = 2;
      }
      if (Ind.random === 2) {
        sum.push(x);
        x--;
        if (x != 0) {
          Ind(x);
        }
        return sum;
      }
    }
    console.log(Ind(10));

  // Here's how I did it with switch (The code is longer though).

  function Index(start, end) { // 1) Start and end are used as input
    switch (start) {
      case "Second_run":  // 4) Second time running
        output = [];      // 5) declares output array 
        start = "Third_run"; 
        Index(start, end) 
        break;
      case "Third_run": // 6) Third time running.
        save++;
        output.push(save); // 7) The value of save is saved in output
        if (save == end) {  // 8) Functions is re-executed, conditions met
          return output
        }
        Index(start, end) 
        break
      default: // 2) The function starts here and saves start's value as save
        save = start;
        start = "Second_run";  // 3) It chages start's value to "Second_run" 
        Index(start, end) 
        break;
    }
    return output
  }
  console.log(Index(0, 10));

// Here's the first one, but with start and end (same concept with small changes)

function Ind(start, end) {
  if (Ind.random === undefined) {
    output = [];
    Ind.random = 2;
  }
  if (Ind.random === 2) {
    output.push(start);
    start++;
    if (start <= end) {
      Ind(start, end);
    }
    return output;
  }
}
console.log(Ind(10, 15));
```

Comment: which version is not working and what is the expected output?

Comment: All of them work. But I want version 1 to require a single input which is the number of items it wants to put into the array. Like Independent(10) run function. Output array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to make the function avoid executing certain code based on the result of previous executions WITHOUT using global variables or parameters.

Remember that in JavaScript, a function is also an object. This means that a function can have properties, much like the object of a class.

So the nice thing is you can access and set properties each time your function is executed, and then execute the code you want based on that.

Here is a pretty simple example:

```
function Independent()
{
   /*First check if the property has already been defined */
   if (Independent.SomeProperty === undefined) {
         Independent.SomeProperty = 1;
         console.log("This is the first time Independent() is being called");
   }


   else if (Independent.SomeProperty === 2) {
       console.log("This is the second time Independent() is being called");
       //Your code here
   }

   else if (Independent.SomeProperty === 3) {
       console.log("This is the third time Independent() is being called");
       //Your code here
   }

   //etc.


  Independent.SomeProperty++;             //Increment your property here.
}
```

You could even use a `switch` statement if your function will be called more than a few times. Or you could make the value wrap around back to 0 after the function has been called a certain number of times. There are many other possibilities as well. It just depends on your specific requirements.

Comment: Ok, I tried it with switch and it works. But it ended up being a long code. So I came back to manipulating properties and surprisingly it looked really simple when I used function.random === undefined. I'll be posting the final version with the arrays on the top. Thanks again, appreciate the help.

Comment: @VictorYerz No problem. Glad to help =D